# How can I checkout a branch name having special character '-'?

Tags: git

I created a git branch name `-new-br`:

```
git checkout -b -new-br.
```

I switched back to parent branch.

Now I am unable to checkout `-new-br`.

```
git checkout -new-br.
getting error:
error: unknown switch `n'
usage: git checkout [options] <branch>
   or: git checkout [options] [<branch>] -- <file>...
```

How can I check this branch out?

Comment: Did you tried  `git checkout -b \-new\-br`

Comment: Are you sure you created that branch? If i try the `git checkout -b -new-br` command I get: `fatal: '-new-br' is not a valid branch name.`. Check with `git branch -a` if that branch really exists.

Answer (score 8):

Many Unix commands accept `--` to mean "no more switches" and further arguments aren't then parsed as switches. See "[What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/2818)" on [this adjacent site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

So...

```
git checkout -- -new-br
```

...would probably suffice.

However... which version of Git are you using to create such a branch? Git version 1.8.4 tells me:

```
git checkout -b -new-br
fatal: '-new-br' is not a valid branch name.
```

Trying it another way...

```
git branch -- -new-br
fatal: '-new-br' is not a valid branch name
```

I suggest that you check the names of all your branches with:

```
git branch --list --all
```

#### Reference:

- [git-branch(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Comment: Getting this to work is not a sign you should be doing this. Is it really necessary to have a leading dash in your branch name?!

Comment: @S.Spencer: I certainly wasn't advocating such a branch name!

Comment: I wasnt looking at you :)

Answer (score 8):

This works!
Add your branch name inside quotes

```
git checkout '<new-branch-name>'
```

Comment: Single quotes worked on Git Bash but not on Windows Command Prompt (CMD).

Answer (score 5):

If you have an existing branch like that, you can rename it by changing the reference file for the branch:

```
mv .git/refs/heads/-new-br .git/refs/heads/new-br
```

After that, you can check it out using `git checkout new-br`.

Comment: You can also just `ls .git/refs/heads/ -l` and get/copy the wanted branch name.

Comment: thank you, looking at the location `.git/refs/heads` I discover how the unicode character was interpreted by git, and then renaming from within the branch with the command `git branch -m <new branch name>`