# Manage branch names containing invisible symbols

Tags: git

I have a local Git repository and some branches appear to exist, for example:

```
master
test
branch1
branch2
branch3
```

However, when I try to checkout or delete `branch2`, Git says that there is no such branch. In addition, I *can* create a new branch with the same name (`branch2`).

As far as I understand, I somehow managed to put invisible symbols in the branch names. When I do `git branch`, I can see `branch2` but in reality it's `branch2x`, where `x` is some invisible symbol. Copying names from the screen helped with some branches, but not with all.

So my question is: Is there any way to manage branches without knowing their exact names. By position, by Id or any other way?

Comment: write `git branch` in the console and it will list all branches in your project. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Comment: You could try the solutions for renaming the branch as discussed in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15372154/216074) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970918/216074). I’d also suggest you to use a console that can handle Unicode properly and then copy the name exactly from the `git branch` output.

Comment: You could try to let autocomplete help you. Type `git branch -m branch2<Tab>` and then a normal name without special symbols.

Comment: My favorite trick is to use `git branch` or `git for-each-ref` but pipe the output through a command that visually-expands all non-printing characters. The "right" command (opinion warning) for this is `vis` if you have it, but it's BSD-specific.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to work with Git branches without using either a name or possibly a commit hash ID.  If you don't know the names of your branches, I would suggest that you remedy that problem first before you proceed further.  To get your local repository up to date with the latest information, try doing the following:

```
git fetch origin     # brings in all latest remote branches
git branch -a        # shows all local and remote branches
```

Whatever the `git branch -a` commands shows you should be the state of the art with regard to what branches are avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete the branches using the `tig` command.

Use <kbd>r</kbd> to see all git references (branch names, tags, etc).  From there you can <kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to highlight the branch in question and then <kbd>!</kbd> to run `git branch -D` on the selected branch.  Press <kbd>h</kbd> for more information on available `tig` commands.

I had the same problem after copy-and-pasting a branch name from a bug tracker webpage.  In this case, my branch was prefixed with the Unicode `<U+0096> START OF GUARDED AREA` character.  Because of the prefix, tab completion was no help.  Once again, `tig` saved the day.